# Marketing Cloud scheduled Emails based on Salesforce Lead status update

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to send Emails to the leads after their status changes to a specific value and after 24 hours the status change happens. I want to do this every day. Create a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud as well as create an Email list that gets updated with these Leads and other selected lead fields every 24 hours without any duplicates. I was able to find something close where they suggested me to use reports in Salesforce, import it through Interaction studio in Marketing Cloud and then use Automation Studio to send the Emails. I am not sure if it's the best way to do it and also if I can do Data Extractions and Email Lists as mentioned above. I am able to find brief and partial answers but not a complete solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to set up the Marketing Cloud Connector between the CRM and Marketing Cloud. This connection will enable synchronized data that you can use to generate the email list you are looking for. You can even use the Salesforce Data Journey Entry feature to kick off that email in near real-time.
Here's the trailhead that goes over what the Connector can do and how to set it up: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect